# How to make simple role based authorization in AngularJS and FireBase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-routing, user-roles

I want to make a simple role based authorization in AngularJS and FireBase (admin, user).
I made the base authorization, and routing (look at 3 files below).

I found a [repository](https://github.com/colthreepv/angular-login-example) in github and [article](https://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/) but code is too hard for me.
Is there an easier way? How do I change my code to add this functionality?
I would be grateful for links to articles and repositories that can help me.

---

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module( 'journalApp', [ 'firebase', 'ngRoute' ] );

app.constant( 'FIREBASE', '<FIREBASE URL>' );

app.config( [ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function( $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {

    $routeProvider.when( '/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtl'
    } );

    $routeProvider.when( '/logout', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'loginCtl',
        resolve: {
            "logout": [ "authService", function( authService ) {
                authService.signOut();
            }]
        }
    } );

    $routeProvider.when( '/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        resolve: {
            "currentAuth": [ "authService", function( authService ) {
                var auth = authService.auth();
                return auth.$requireSignIn();
            }]
        }
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise( {
        redirectTo: '/'
    } );

    $locationProvider.html5Mode( true );

} ] );

app.run( [ "$rootScope", "$location", function( $rootScope, $location ) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(event, next, previous, error) {
        if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
            $location.path("/login");
        }
    });
} ] );
```

---

**loginCtrl.js**

```
app.controller( 'loginCtrl', [ 'authService', function( authService ) {
    var self = this;

    self.signUp = function() {
        authService.createUser(self.email, self.password);
    };

    self.logIn = function() {
        authService.authUser(self.loginEmail, self.loginPassword);
    };

    self.signOut = function() {
        authService.signOut();
    };
}]);
```

---

**authFactory.js**

```
app.factory( 'authService',  [ '$firebaseAuth', '$window', function( $firebaseAuth, $window ) {

    var authService = {};

    var auth = $firebaseAuth(firebase.auth());

    authService.createUser = function(email, password) {
        auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email, password );
    };

    authService.authUser = function( email, password ) {
        auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword( email, password ).then(function( user ) {
            $window.location.href = "/";
        }, function( error ) {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.info( "Error in authUser - errorCode: " + errorCode + ". errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
        });
    };

    authService.signOut = function() {
        auth.$signOut();
    };

    authService.auth = function() {
        return auth;
    };

    return authService;
}]);
```

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a lot information about how to make it.

---

**Articles / guides / answers from stackoverflow**

- [Article about advanced data modelling and role based authorization](https://fadeit.dk/blog/2016/08/25/firebase-advanced-data-modelling-and-role-based-authentication-authorization/)
- [Article about role based routing in AngularJS](http://mammal.io/articles/robust-role-based-routing-in-angular/) (by [ng-mm-route](https://github.com/mammaldev/ng-mm-route))
- [Little guide about developing a permission-based authorization system in a AngularJS app](http://www.stefanoscerra.it/permission-based-auth-system-in-angularjs/)
- [Article about authorization and role based permissions in AngularJs](http://nadeemkhedr.com/how-to-do-authorization-and-role-based-permissions-in-angularjs/)
- [Good solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20971528/5124009)
- [Recommendation from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217990/5124009) ([angular permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission))

**Helpful repositories**

- [Basic user profile management](https://github.com/cliffhall/angular-firebase-user-profiles)
- [Demo to show how to use Angular + Firebase + Google Material Design together](https://github.com/tarlepp/Angular-Firebase-Material-Demo)
- [Simple Login (Facebook, Twitter, Google, Github) and Chat Application with Angular and Firebase](https://github.com/bcokca/angular-firebase)
- [Role based authorization for Firebase](https://github.com/henry-hz/angular-firebase-auth)
- [Role-based permissions for AngularJS](https://github.com/mikemclin/angular-acl)
- [Stand-alone project showing how to make a robust angular application serving access permissions from Server](https://github.com/colthreepv/angular-login-example)

Comment: Nice repository of links! I also highly recommend "neat trick #2" from this talk at this year's I/O: https://youtu.be/5hYMDfDoHpI?t=9m13s

Comment: Firebase just launched support for role based access via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims